# Are there remote sensing experts who attend this community?

Tags: discussion, support

Regarding [this discussion](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11581/remote-sensing-in-geoscience) that took place about 1 year ago and considering all the comments, I want to have a similar discussion here since Signal Processing is a community related to remote sensing because new remote sensing techniques such as SAR and RADAR Remote Sensing envolve with the processing of radar signals and need to use signal processing concepts in their studies.

I suspect there are some geodesists, photogrammetrists, surveyors, remote sensing experts who attend in this community, so I want them participate in this discussion.

I think that there are concepts in remote sensing that cannot be covered just in GIS.SE and I have given some reasons [here](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4019/19874), [here](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21707/142064) and [here](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21610/142064).

I also have created a proposal for a new site:

[Check out the Area 51 Remote Sensing Proposal http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/90327.png](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/90327/geomatics-and-remote-sensing?referrer=8G2asYAyI_To9RoVf1VtPg2)

And I want to ask the remote sensing experts who attend here

**Are you interested in having a new site?**

**If yes, which percent of remote sensing experts attending this community you think will support the new site?**

I just beg you that participate in the discussion. Even a small comment will be considered. I have some doubts about whether we really need a new site or not?

**Also a chat room has been created http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29875/remote-sensing-and-photogrammetry-proposal**